# i18n: Sanitize keys before lookup?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization

I'm running into some issues with i18n (we use react-i18next). Some of our library of translations have whitespace before or after, capitalization(s), and/or a trailing period in the keys.

The callsite reference doesn't perfectly match at times and this creates lookup failures.

We want to trim a target key on both sides, remove ending punctuation, and lowercase everything before lookup. Example:

```
// locales/section1/fr.js
{ "Hello! ": "Bonjour" }


// Component.js inside return()
<div>{section1:hello}</div>
```

Is it possible to have the above lookup match? If so, how is it done?

Comment: Would it be easier to clean up the locales files on import?

Comment: @nipuna777 interesting idea. I am thinkng of running a bash script as part of `npm run dev`. Or did you have another idea? you mentioned doing it during import of the library which is different. We import react-i18n in many files, not just the root component

Comment: By 'import' I actually meant the importing of translations to the project, sorry about the confustion. But having a script to do the cleanup sounds like a good solution. You could have it as a separete script that runs as part of the 'dev' as well.